# How can I land for a treasure hunt in Sid Meier's Pirates for the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, sid-meiers-pirates

I got a complete treasure map and I know where to land to find it.
But I cannot, my ship keep bouncing on the beach.

I played that game long ago on my computer and I'm trying the Wii version. I don't remember if I had to do something special on the PC version, what I remember is that I just had to crash on the beach to get a party on foot, but I did not find how to do this on the Wii version.

Comment: Not saying this works but it's worth trying. When on the shore where a treasure is, pull out your telescopic lens and browse the shore around the X on your map until you see your target. Then attempt to land on the shore. You may need a button press (A) to land instead of moving into the shore. I will post as an answer if it works.

Comment: @thethinman That was it! I had to use telescopic lens so the treasure show in the landscape. There is no "party on foot" on the WII, it was the fact the I played it on PC before that confused me... Post it as an answer and you will get the Bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When on the shore where the treasure is, pull out your telescopic lens and browse the shore around the X on your map (marking the treasure's location) until you see your target. Then attempt to land on the shore.

Comment: No need to press a button.

Comment: what i want to now is how to do it whithout the tellescope

Comment: @user16022 I don't believe you can do it without a telescopic lens.

Answer (score 0):

Hold b on the wii remote and use the telescope, when your telescope finds the treasure, you will appear at the treasure and it will say "after several hours of digging, you discovered ________ buried treasure worth _______ gold pieces" or something like that, no need to land just see it with the cursor and It will be found